# Bash script compare values from 2 files and print output values from one file

Tags: bash, awk, diff, comm

I have two files like this;

> File1
>           `114.4.21.198,cl_id=1J3W7P7H0S3L6g85900g736h6_101ps`
>           `114.4.21.205,cl_id=1O3M7A7Q0S3C6h85902g7b3h7_101pf`
>           `114.4.21.205,cl_id=1W3C7Z7W0U3J6795197g177j9_117p1`
>           `114.4.21.213,cl_id=1I3A7J7N0M3W6e950i7g2g2i0_1020h`
>
> File2
>   `cl_id=1B3O7M6C8T4O1b559i2g930m0_1165d`
>   `cl_id=1X3J7M6J0W5S9535180h90302_101p5`
>   `cl_id=1G3D7X6V6A7R81356e3g527m9_101nl`
>   `cl_id=1L3J7R7O0F0L74954h2g495h8_117qk`
>   `cl_id=1L3J7R7O0F0L74954h2g495h8_117qk`
>   `cl_id=1J3W7P7H0S3L6g85900g736h6_101ps`
>   `cl_id=1W3C7Z7W0U3J6795197g177j9_117p1`
>   `cl_id=1I3A7J7N0M3W6e950i7g2g2i0_1020h`
>   `cl_id=1Q3Y7Q7J0M3E62953e5g3g5k0_117p6`

I want to compare cl_id values that exist on file1 but not exist on file2 and print out the first values from file1 (IP Address).

it should be like this

> `114.4.21.198`
>   `114.4.21.205`
>   `114.4.21.205`
>   `114.4.21.213`
>   `114.4.23.70`
>   `114.4.21.201`
>   `114.4.21.211` 
>   `120.172.168.36`

I have tried awk,grep diff, comm. but nothing come close. Please tell the correct command to do this.

thanks

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and your train of thought.  This tends to get better responses than simply asking for the solution.

Comment: The `join` command is built to join files.

Comment: Your sample output contains values that are not in the sample inputs. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

One proper way to that is this:

`grep -vFf file2 file1 | sed 's|,cl_id.*$||'`

Comment: This returns `114.4.21.205` not the same as reqested

Comment: @Jotne He said "values that exist on file1 **but not** exist on file2".

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how you get your output.  Where does 120.172.168.36 come from.
Here is one solution to compare

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++;next} !a[$1] {print $1}' file2 file1
114.4.21.198
114.4.21.205
114.4.21.205
114.4.21.213
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like what you want to do and might work, efficiently:

```
grep -Ff file2.txt file1.txt | cut -f1 -d,
```

First the `grep` takes the lines from `file2.txt` to use as patterns, and finds the matching lines in `file1.txt`. The `-F` is to use the patterns as literal strings rather then regular expressions, though it doesn't really matter with your sample.

Finally the `cut` takes the first column from the output, using `,` as the column delimiter, resulting in a list of IP addresses.

The output is not exactly the same as your sample, but the sample didn't make sense anyway, as it contains text that was not in any of the input files. Not sure if this is what you wanted or something more.

Answer (score 0):

Feed both files into AWK or perl with field separator=",". If there are two fields, add the fields to a dictionary/map/two arrays/whatever ("file1Lines"). If there is just one field (this is file 2), add it to a set/list/array/whatever ("file2Lines"). After reading all input:

Loop over the file1Lines. For each element, check whether the key part is present in file2Lines. If not, print the value part.